# Arduino Sketch not uploading into my Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino

I bought an Arduino Nano for a simple project and when I tried to upload a simple program:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

it didn't worked!

I did some research about my problem and haven't found a solution yet.

Here's a screenshot of what the compiler said:
[image: Screenshot of my Arduino IDE]

I also tried the COM1 to see if I messed up with that and still nothing seemed to work:
[image]

I checked in devices, as proposed in other questions here, and it seems to be no problem, (windows 10):

[image: Screenshot of settings in my laptop]

[image]

Again, I haven't found a solution yet for my problem, and my project is due in week and a half. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Instead of unreadable screenshots of the compiler messages, why don't you just copy and paste the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 kinds of Arduino boards sold in the China taobao.com, the original designed boards and the so called 'upgraded' boards which use cheaper chips but you need to install the ch340 drivers.  I tried both and I found that the so called upgraded, cheaper boards are unstable!  Since the price of the board has a different of only less than one us dollar, I would suggest you buy another arduino board with the original chips, i.e. you don't have to install the ch340 driver.